# jQuery binding event unbinding itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, keydown, keyup

I set a `keyup` and a `keydown` event on a searchbar element. It works fine the first time around, but after that it does nothing anymore. Here is my code:

```
$("#q").keyup(function(event){ //code });
$("#q").keydown(function(event){ //code });
```

Within the code for each event is the same timeout function that calls an ajax query to a search script that sends back a JSON encoded data. I have the timeout set at 150.

Comment: What sits inside of those functions? On their own, there is no issue. It's a PEBKAC.

Comment: I added some extra details

Comment: can you share what is happening inside those callback functions

Comment: Sorry, based on the supplied information, [I cannot replicate this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/rTKP6/).

Comment: I dont know what to say. I type in a string, i get the results, i delete the string, i get other results, than i retype something into the search bar and get no results anymore. thats all i can say

Comment: We need to see more of your code...specifically where you currently have the `//code` comments. I'm assuming you've checked to make sure no errors are appearing in the console?